# Why does insert error 1062 occur, although it should not be?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Server version: 10.3.22-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 - Debian 10

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `background` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `data` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '[]',
  `priority` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `attempt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `add` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `update` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2002280000000127419 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
 PARTITION BY RANGE (`id`)
(PARTITION `d200226` VALUES LESS THAN (2002270000000000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `d200227` VALUES LESS THAN (2002280000000000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `d200228` VALUES LESS THAN (2002290000000000000) ENGINE = InnoDB)
```

Periodically, an error 1062 occurs during insertion

```
INSERT INTO `background` (`name`, `data`, `priority`, `time`, `status`, `add`) VALUES ('move', '{\"id\":2002280000000000448,\"frame\":18}', 1, 1582840572, 0, 1582840572)
```

I looked on the Internet, advised innodb_autoinc_lock_mode to change from 1 to 2, but this did not help, errors still occur.

**Question**: what to do?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: *an error 1062 occurs during insertion* Give FULL error message text, without restrictions/editions. If it may vary give all possible variants.

Comment: @Akina, for example "Duplicate entry '2002280000000181365' for key 'PRIMARY'". Moreover, in 20 parallel requests, the duplicate key ID is the same ..

Comment: 1) Does this value exists really in the database? 2) How does the same AUTO_INCREMENT value must be generated in separate parallel queries? I don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 1062 error is "Duplicate entry for key".

The only unique constrain in your table is `` PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ``.

I see 2 possible reasons in shown environ:

1) Manual update of `id` field value (or insert new record with specifying `id` value). When autoincrement generator gives the value which is already present in the table the error occured.

2) There exists some trigger which fires while inserting, it inserts data into or updates data in some another table, and the values inserted/updated causes some unique constraint violation.

For to select what reason occures in your particular case you must show full text of the error message.

Comment: Past .. no manual insertion, no triggers. But, insertion occurs as part of the transaction.

Comment: @BigTon *But, insertion occurs as part of the transaction.* it doesn't matter.